# can't install Cocoapods after installed Ruby

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, cocoapods

I recently installed and used ruby,
now I'm not sure why I can't use CocoaPods,

I get this error :

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError

Comment: Did you install ruby with homebrew?

Comment: yes I did i' used - 
 `rvm use ruby-2.4.2@myAppName --ruby-version --create`
and then
gem install rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using RVM or Rbenv for managing your ruby versions. To install cocoapods you can do `gem install cocoapods`. Then, in your project folder you can run `pod install`.